# What is the correct way to parse this JSON object in C#?

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

This is the JSON object I am receiving from a GET request:

```
{
"data": {
    "valve_maker": [],
    "water_volume": [
        "15L",
        "20L",
        "..."
    ],
    "cylinder_manufacturer": [
        "Tianhai"
    ],
    "qc_stamp": [
        "TS"
    ],
    "reference_standard": [
        "GB 5099"
    ],
    "production_licence": [
        "TS2210752-2016"
    ],
    "valve_production_licence": [
        "TSF210030"
    ],
    "rate_of_residual_deformation": {
        "1": "<3%",
        "2": "<10%"
    },
    "material_number": {
        "1": "30CrMo",
        "2": "34CrMo4",
        "3": "..."
    },
    "heat_treatment": {
        "1": "...",
        "2": "..."
    },
    "drawing_number": {
        "1": "...",
        "2": "..."
    },
    "cylinder_thickness": []
}
```

right now, I am able to parse JSON objects with a simpler structure like :

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "gas_id": "ID of the gas",
        "gas_name": "Gas name"
    }
]
```

by using something like this:

```
private void jsonparsegas(string res)
    {
        JObject par = JObject.Parse(res);
        foreach (JToken data in par["data"].Children())
        {
            string id = data["gas_id"].ToString();
            string name = data["gas_name"].ToString();
            if (this.cmbCylType.Items.Contains(name) == false)
            {
                this.cmbCylType.Items.Add(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to apply the same thing to the more complicated JSON object, I get an error:

```
private void jsonparsecoc(string res)
    {
        //JObject par = JObject.Parse(res);
        var jObj = (JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
        foreach (var child in jObj["data"].Children())   
        {

            string vMaker = child["valve_maker"].ToString(); //error thrown here right away
            string wVolume = child["water_volume"].ToString();
            string cMan = child["cylinder_manufacturer"].ToString();
            string QC = child["qc_stamp"].ToString();
            string rStandard = child["reference_standard"].ToString();
            string pLicence = child["production_licence"].ToString();
            string VPL = child["valve_production_licence"].ToString();
            string rrd = child["rate_of_residual_deformation"].ToString();
            string mNum = child["material_number"].ToString();
            string hTreatment = child["heat_treatment"].ToString();
            string dNum = child["drawing_number"].ToString();
            string cThick = child["cylinder_thickness"].ToString();

        }
```

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty

I have tried a few different things I found on StackOverflow, but I don't really understand how Deserializing of the objects works.  The simpler parsing works just fine, and allows me to add all "gas_name"s that I receive from my GET request to a combobox.  The format the first "valve_maker" child of "data" seems to have the same structure as "gas_id" or "gas_name" in the more similar JSON object, but this is where I receive the error right away.  If I had to guess at a cause for the error, I'd say it has something to do with the difference between using

> "valve_maker": []

and using

> "gas_id": "ID of the gas"

in the objects. also I notice "data" is followed by [] brackets in the simpler one, and {} in the more complicated one.

If anyone could link to some good reading material, or offer a good explanation of a solution/what's going on, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: {} is a class in c#, [] is an array, a collection, a list, [{},{},{}] is an array of classes, {'array': []} is a class with an array property....

Comment: Ordinarily I'd say to use http://json2csharp.com/ to produce a class structure, and then use the generic `DeserializeObject<>()` signature to create a strongly-typed, structured result. However, your sample input has some numbers in it as the names of properties, which isn't allowed on C# objects. Do those types of objects have a fixed structure, or are they going to have an arbitrary number of properties on them?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior You can use [an attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm) to override the name.

Comment: @KennethK.: I know. However, the use of numbers begs the question: does `rate_of_residual_deformation` always have exactly two properties, or does it have any number of properties? If the former, then using an attribute is a good strategy. If the latter, then a `Dictionary<,>` is probably a more appropriate structure.

Comment: rate_of_residual_deformation, and the other ones with numbers, will have a different number of properties some times.  I'm going to ask the guy on the database side of things to remove those and let me infer the numbers from their index in a combobox later.  Thanks for the link to json2csharp.  Should help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is the key to the problem you're having:

> in the objects. also I notice "data" is followed by [] brackets in the simpler one, and {} in the more complicated one.

In [JSON](http://www.json.org/),

- `[]` brackets enclose an array
- `{}` brackets enclose an object

In both code examples, you are digging into the object by looping through the results using `par["data"].Children()`.  To be consistent with the JSON model, JSON.NET defines different behavior for resolving children of [objects](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#LC65) and  [arrays](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JArray.cs#LC45).  The children of an object are its properties and the children of an array are its items.

In your code, the input to `jsonparsegas` is an array of simple objects with 2 properties where the input to `jsonparsecoc` is a single complex objects with many properties.

In `jsonparsegas`, the `Children()` call gives you an array of all the simple gas objects.  You loop through these objects and extract the values of "gas_id" and "gas_name" for each object.  In your example data, there only happens to be one gas object so your code only executes once.

In `jsonparsecoc`, the `Children()` call actually gives you **property values for the properties of the complex object, since the result is an object and not an array**.  So, when you loop through this result you can't access things like "valve_maker", because they are defined on the complex object and you have already stepped into the value for `valve_maker` then this executes.

The solution is simple.  **Don't loop through the properties** in `jsonparsecoc`.  Instead of `foreach(var child in jObj["data"].Children())` you need something like `var child = jObj["data"];`.  This will give you the reference to the **object** that actually contains each of the properties you are trying to access.

Comment: haha thanks, this helped a lot.  I had lost sight of the fact that the simpler one was an example of one of many that I looped through and that the complex one was only one big thing and didnt need looping.

Answer (score 1):

@smartcaveman did a good job of explaining what is going wrong with your code.  However, you might find your data a little easier to process if you defined strongly-typed classes for it like this:

```
class RootObject
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("valve_maker")]
    public List<string> ValveMaker { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("water_volume")]
    public List<string> WaterVolume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cylinder_manufacturer")]
    public List<string> CylinderManufacturer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("qc_stamp")]
    public List<string> QCStamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reference_standard")]
    public List<string> ReferenceStandard { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("production_licence")]
    public List<string> ProductionLicense { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("valve_production_licence")]
    public List<string> ValveProductionLicense { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rate_of_residual_deformation")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> RateOfResidualDeformation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("material_number")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> MaterialNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("heat_treatment")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> HeatTreatment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("drawing_number")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> DrawingNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cylinder_thickness")]
    public List<string> CylinderThickness { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize the JSON to your classes like this:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p0D7ze

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Test{
    public Data data{get;set;}
}

public class Data{
     public List<string> Value_maker{get;set;}
    public List<String> Water_Volume{get;set;}
    public List<String> cylinder_manufacturer{get;set;}
}
```

Create Class structure Like that and after that use to deserialize
Jsonconvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString)
it will convert json into proper object, keep in mind structure should be proper and property name should be same as your json property
Hope It will Help you